# Graph abstraction of a polynomial equation?

Tags: polynomials

It seems to me that a polynomial equation may be abstractly modelled as a converging graphlike "tree", similar to Abstract Syntax Trees in Computer Programming.

Variables may be considered as nodes, operations as branches, and the additive identity as the roots. Morphisms in this space would have to equate to transformations of a polynomial, with a uniquely reducible form.

Does such a formalised structure exist in mathematics?

Answer (score 0):

In symbolic calculus is usual represent the expressions as trees. See [Computer Algebra Systems](http://www.math.wpi.edu/IQP/BVCalcHist/calc5.html).